# Get lines with dates less than current date

Tags: awk

I have a file which has a date at the beginning of each line.
I want to get all lines which has a date that is less than the current date.

Here is what I have,

When I used this:

```
awk '$NF < "2020-10-27"' expiry.txt >sample.txt
```

I was able to get a desired output

But when I substitute the date above "2020-10-27" to date today , I got no result

My script:

```
date=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
awk '$NF < "$date"' expiry.txt
```

sample logs in the file

```
2020-05-30: /tmp/abcd
2019-08-21: /tmp/abcde
2020-03-22: /tmp/abcdef
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Based on your shown samples and attempts, could you please try following.

```
awk -v dat="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')" -F':' '$1<dat' Input_file
```

***Multiple fixes in OP's attempts:***

- There was no proper value passed from shell variable to `awk` code.
- Now coming to major issue, OP has used `$NF` which is last field of line but as per sample date is coming in very first field of lines, so changed it to `$1`(first field).
- OP has used default field separator(space for `awk`), to catch the exact date and make it first field I have made field separator as `:` so that only date value is picked up for match with `dat` variable.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code: the shell will not substitute the `$date` variable if it's within single quotes. So you are comparing the date in column 1 against the literal string `"$date"`. And because the ASCII value of `$` is smaller than the ASCII value of `2`, the $1 value is always lexically greater than the string `"$date"`. Hence, no output.

If you have GNU awk, you can use the builtin [time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html)

```sh
gawk '
  BEGIN {today = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", systime())}
  $1 < today
' Input_file
```